# How to add composites to a scrolled container composite in SWT

Tags: java, swt, jfreechart

I'm trying to create a scrollable container window to which I can add JFreeChart step charts, one under another, based on some values from different files but I am encountering a couple of problems. One of them is the fact that I'm not able 
to put the ChartComposite objects in the container, once I run the program it shows an empty window. I'm surely doing something wrong but I honestly have no idea how it should be.

Here's the code on how I try to put some charts into a container.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    final ScrolledComposite scrolled = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL);
    Composite comp = new Composite(scrolled, SWT.NONE);
    scrolled.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    final JFreeChart chart = createChart();
    final JFreeChart chart1 = createChart();
    final JFreeChart chart2 = createChart();
    final JFreeChart chart3 = createChart();

    new ChartComposite(comp, SWT.NONE, chart, true);
    new ChartComposite(comp, SWT.NONE, chart1, true);
    new ChartComposite(comp, SWT.NONE, chart2, true);
    new ChartComposite(comp, SWT.NONE, chart3, true);

    comp.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    scrolled.setContent(comp);

    scrolled.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrolled.setExpandHorizontal(true);

    scrolled.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);

    scrolled.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
            org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle r = scrolled.getClientArea();
            scrolled.setMinSize(parent.computeSize(r.width, SWT.DEFAULT));
        }
    });

}
```

Any help or a link to some great tutorials on how to do stuff like this would be welcome.

EDIT: Did try a little with ScrolledComposite, modified the code accordingly, but it expands the charts to fit the whole view and is by no means scrollable.

Comment: In SWT a ascrollable container is called `ScrolledComposite`, the [SWT snipppets](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) show some examples of how to use this widget.

Comment: I found the Group container, in the meanwhile, which can be made scrollabe by setting its style. Problem now is the ChartComposites autoresize to fit all in one window which means if I have say 20 charts they're gonna be pretty squished. Do you know if I could add them to something of a ChartPanel, which I can set it's dimensions?

Comment: If you refer to the `Group` widget, note that this widget is not scrollable. The JavaDoc of a widget lists the applicable style flags. Only controls inheriting of `Scrollable` may provide scrollbars. Use a `ScrolledComposite ` instead.

Comment: Well just adding   ScrolledComposite scrolled = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL);
  new ChartComposite(scrolled, SWT.NONE, chart, true); doesn't seem to work, as it shows an empty window. Guess I'll have to look at those snippets.

Comment: Modified the code with Scrolled Composite but the charts seem to auto resize to fill the view, making the view not scrollable.

Comment: Calling `scrolled.setLayout()` is unnecessary (see the JavaDoc).

Comment: Thanks, I noticed too. Also the ScrolledComposite works ok now, my current problem at the moment is with those ChartComposites that keep resizing, whereas I'm trying to get them to a fixed size. But that's for another question. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Please consider to delete this question. I think it is unlikely that it will help others having difficulties with ScroledComposites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example for you to adapt:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  Display display = new Display();
  Shell shell = new Shell( display );
  shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() );
  ScrolledComposite scrolled = new ScrolledComposite( shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL );
  scrolled.setExpandVertical( true );
  scrolled.setExpandHorizontal( true );
  scrolled.setAlwaysShowScrollBars( true );
  Composite composite = new Composite( scrolled, SWT.NONE );
  composite.setLayout( new FillLayout( SWT.VERTICAL ) );
  for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
    Composite item = new Composite( composite, SWT.NONE );
    item.setBackground( item.getDisplay().getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_BLACK + i ) );
  }
  scrolled.setContent( composite );
  scrolled.setMinSize( composite.computeSize( SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT ) );
  scrolled.addControlListener( new ControlAdapter() {
    public void controlResized( ControlEvent event ) {
      Rectangle clientArea = scrolled.getClientArea();
      scrolled.setMinSize( composite.computeSize( clientArea.width, SWT.DEFAULT ) );
    }
  } );
  shell.setSize( 300, 300 );
  shell.open();
  while( !shell.isDisposed() ) {
    if( !display.readAndDispatch() )
      display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
}
```

The `item`s represent your `CharComposite`s. If that doesn't show the desired result, you need to revise the `ChartComposite::computeSize()` implementation, or use a single columned `GridLayout` and control the size of the charts through `GridData::widthHint` and `heightHint`.