# Setting a JFreeChart ChartComposite to a fixed size in SWT

Tags: java, swt, jfreechart

I'm trying to add JFree step charts to a scrollable view in eclipse as a plugin, but the charts keep resizing (kinda randomly) each time I modify the view's dimensions.

I want to set them to a fixed size, however large or small the view might get (that's why I made it scrollable in the first place) so I tried something like this:

```
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {
    ScrolledComposite scrolled = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);        

    Composite comp = new Composite(scrolled, SWT.NONE);
    comp.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    final JFreeChart chart = createChart();

    ChartComposite chartComposite1 = new ChartComposite(comp, SWT.NONE, chart, true);

    // set chart size attempt 

    chartComposite1.setSize(500, 200);
    chartComposite1.redraw();
    comp.redraw();
    scrolled.redraw();

    // ScrolledComposite stuff

    scrolled.setContent(comp);

    scrolled.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrolled.setExpandHorizontal(true);

    scrolled.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(true);

    scrolled.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
        public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
            org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle r = scrolled.getClientArea();
            scrolled.setMinSize(parent.computeSize(r.width, SWT.DEFAULT));
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't do anything. The chart keeps auto resizing as I modify the view's size.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you undestand how layouts work in SWT. [Understanding Layouts in SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) is a good start.

`chartComposite1.setSize()` is useless, it will be *overwritten* by the layout that was set in `comp.setLayout( ... )`.

... and forcing controls to `redraw()` doesn't help either as it doesn't update the location or size of controls.

[As I suggested earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481530/how-to-add-composites-to-a-scrolled-container-composite-in-swt), if you know the size of the charts, use a single columned `GridLayout` and control the size of the charts through `GridData::widthHint` and `heightHint`.

Comment: Yes GridLayout worked perfectly. First I actually tried with a RowLayout but it only accepted a fixed size, while GridLayout permitted me to fill horizontaly while maintaing a fixed size vetically. Thanks a lot!